# android facebook sdk app: minimum android version

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

What's the minimum version of an android app taking advantage of the latest android facebook sdk 3.0 ?
I'm reading this in the facebook sdk source manifest: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`.

Can it be as low as SDK_INT=4 if we're using the android-support-v4.jar library ? Or will the facebook library make our apps impossible to use on versions lower than sdkint=8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried using with (api 4), the facebook 3.0 sdk does not work and crashes with it.  Went to the next highest (android 2.1 api 7) and that worked....